# Passing Two dimension array from vb.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

```
<script>
  var map,imageServiceLayer;
  var clr_default = [[164355, 71, 107, 161]];
  var clr_custom;
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISImageServiceLayer", 
    "esri/layers/ImageServiceParameters", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, ArcGISImageServiceLayer, 
    ImageServiceParameters, parser
  ) {
    parser.parse();
    esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("http://mapsdev.lib.purdue.edu:6080");

    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",
      center: [-100, 33],
      zoom: 5
    });

    var rasterFunction = new esri.layers.RasterFunction();
    var arguments = {};
    arguments.Colormap=clr_default;
    rasterFunction.arguments = arguments;
    rasterFunction.functionName = "Colormap";
    var params = new ImageServiceParameters();
    //params.renderingRule=rasterFunction;
    imageServiceLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("http://mapsdev.lib.purdue.edu:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ISEE/ISEE2Dev_IN_DBO_gSSURGO_IN_10m/ImageServer", {
      imageServiceParameters: params,
      opacity: 0.75
    });
    map.addLayer(imageServiceLayer);
  });
  function changeColor(val){
    var rasterFunction = new esri.layers.RasterFunction();
    var arguments = {};     
  if (val == "Default")
  imageServiceLayer.setRenderingRule(null);
  else if (val == "Default1")
  {
    arguments.Colormap=clr_default;
    rasterFunction.arguments = arguments;
    rasterFunction.functionName = "Colormap";
    imageServiceLayer.setRenderingRule(rasterFunction);
  }
  else if (val == "Custom")
  {
    arguments.Colormap=clr_custom;
    rasterFunction.arguments = arguments;
    rasterFunction.functionName = "Colormap";
    imageServiceLayer.setRenderingRule(rasterFunction);
  }
  }
</script>

Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.Append("var clr_custom=new Array(" & (i + 1) & ");")
    For j As Integer = 0 To i
        sb.Append("clr_custom[" & j & "]=new Array(4);")
        For k As Integer = 0 To 3
            sb.Append("clr_custom[" & j & "][" & k & "]=" & color(j, k) & ";")
        Next
    Next
```

This is my java script.In fourth line  the variable clr_custom is two dimension array and  need to get values from server database and i tried doing that as shown above in vb.net.One way is to use registerstartupscript() for whole javascript,but this makes difficult to edit java script.Is there any simple to define the variable value in vb.net and use the same variable in javascript

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you just want `<%= sb.ToString() %>` in the middle of your javascript.